# Using pipes with docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

In the example at https://github.com/docker/docker-py, they return the results of a command to a docker image as so:

```
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "echo hello world")
'hello world\n'
```

What I want is to use a pipe - for instance, it would be great if I could do this:

```
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "echo hello world | wc")
'       1       2      12\n'
```

However, instead I get this:

```
 >>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "echo hello world | wc")
    b'hello world | wc\n'
```

What is the easiest way to run two commands, the second piped from the first, in docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply :

```
client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "sh -c 'echo hello world | wc'")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you use a shell construct such as `$ENV_VAR`, `|`, etc, make sure you actually have a shell to interpret them or they'll have their literal values!  To see why your invocation lacks a shell, you have to understand docker `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

If you look at the dockerfile for [ubuntu:latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/),you'll see that it is

```
FROM scratch
```

And the file doesn't set an `ENTRYPOINT`, only a `CMD`.   Read [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) for some good looking info about the difference.  Suffice it to say that in your case everything after the image name replaces the `cmd`.

The doc for `containers.run()` says `command` can be a `str` or `list`.  From that, and from observed behavior, we can infer the command string will be split on whitespace to create a list of arguments for the docker exec.

So, the answer, in short, is because `|` is a shell construct but you're executing no shell.  There's a few ways to add a shell into the equation.  The most obvious is to run the shell directly:

```
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "bash -c 'echo hello world | wc'",)
'      1       2      12\n'
```

But you could also set the entrypoint to a shell, which is commonly done in general purpose containers (though notice you still have to make sure that `-c` is provided, and the entire shell command must be enquoted as before.  The entrypoint only provides the executable, not any arguments).

```
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "-c 'echo hello world | wc'", entrypoint="bash")
'      1       2      12\n'
```

The command line does the same thing with the standard input field separator:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest echo hello world \| wc
hello world | wc
```

If we enquote the whole thing we defeat the automatic splitting around the input field separator:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest "echo hello world \| wc"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo hello world \\\\| wc\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

The python equivalent is:

```
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest",["echo hello world \\|"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [... traceback omitted for brevity ...]
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo hello world \\\\|\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!